# Testing Best Practices possibly with regard to Gherkin but probably not

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cucumber, gherkin

A coworker and I are having an argument about the proper way to test. I'll lay them out as neutrally as I can, and won't give my opinion in this post.

This is written in gherkin. Substitute whatever pseudocode you want to.

```
Given I am a registered user
When I submit my credentials
Then I can login
```

*Case one:*

```
Given I am a registered user 
    (instantiates the user,
    stores the user to scenario-global memory,
    adds the user to the db with an API endpoint
    stores the API endpoint result to scenario-global memory [200, "Success message"])

When I submit my credentials
    (test the result of the previous step [200],
    fills the credential field(s),
    clicks submit, stores the result to scenario-global memory [200, "Success message"])

Then I can login
    (tests the results of the previous step)
```

*Case two:*

```
Given I am a registered user
    (instantiates the user,
    stores the user in scenario-global memory,
    adds the user to the db, tests the result of the db command)

When I submit my credentials
    (fills the UI credential field(s),
    clicks submit)

Then I can login
    (perform some operation that only a logged-in user could do [see the my profile button/call some api endpoint])
```

​

The contention is whether or not the Then step can rely on the result from a previous operation.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. First of all, as a tester, i would never directly write something to DB, instead i register the user in UI for UI testing or call endpoints to cover API testing scenarios.

Also, IMO, not every step is responsible for testing its own step, otherwise there is no need for 'Then' Gherkin syntax. This way of writing user stories makes it more understandable to non-technical but business people very clearly about the scenario under test.

For both cases above, i vote for case one and your co-worker's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Overall, one should aim for declarative BDD scenarios, when trying to cover the features from end-user perspective. Pushing your [how down](http://www.marcusoft.net/2013/04/PushTheHowDown.html) is vital part of it. Employing [Back door manipulation](http://automationisking.blogspot.com/2015/10/back-door-manipulation-api-layer.html) is great, but ask youself this - does your end user (or stakeholder) really care about technicalities?

> adds the user to the db with an API endpoint

is something that is best used, when the `register user` flow is covered at least once through the UI. Mixing APIs and UI in the scenarios, can lead to a mess and maintenance issues. A proper [DSL](https://martinfowler.com/tags/domain%20specific%20language.html) should handle that for you.

As to

> each step is responsible for testing its own results. It is not responsible for what happened in the past or what is about to happen in the future

Cucumber-ish frameworks do use [DI](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/state/#dependency-injection) of context/state, exactly for this - share steps execution run in the current World instance.